# What is Android's <instrumentation> tag equivalent in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap, instrumentation

We need to enable [instrumentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/instrumentation-element.html) in one of our phonegap apps. The given link shows how to enable it for android native apps but I am unable to figure out how to get the same done on a phonegap app. Is there a way to add it it the `config.xml`? And if there is a way would it work for both android and iOS or will we need to do something additional for getting the instrumentation enabled in iOS?

PS: I know there will be standard comments like share your code. But unfortunately I do not have any code to share at the moment because I have no clue as to how to translate it to work in `config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add it it the `config.xml`?

That's the easy part: using recent versions of Phonegap/Cordova, you can simply insert a `<config-file>` block in your `config.xml`, something like:

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <instrumentation android:functionalTest="false"
             android:handleProfiling="true"
             android:icon="drawable resource"
             android:label="string resource"
             android:name="com.example.project.Instrumentation"
             android:targetPackage="com.example.myApp"
             android:targetProcesses="*" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

However there's no built-in functionality for instrumentation in the core Phonegap (Cordova) framework itself, so you'd have to write the native Android implementation of the Instrumentation class yourself.
This would be best wrapped up at as a Phonegap plugin, which would include your custom Java class(es) and the `<config-file>` block would go into the `plugin.xml`.
See the [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) for more details.

> And if there is a way would it work for both android and iOS or will we need to do something additional for getting the instrumentation enabled in iOS?

The `<instrumentation>` tag and associated classes are specific to the Android platform, so a different iOS-specific implementation would be needed; about that, I have no idea :-)

If you're looking for an out-of-the-box solution, I believe there are a few existing plugins such as [dynatrace-cordova-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynatrace-cordova-plugin) which gives some kind of instrumentation at the Javascript level.